# Displaying reputation by tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I spend 99% of my SO time in a specific tag, in my case it is `html-email` (or synonym tags). I've been very active over the last couple years, but to date, only accumulated 5.7K in reputation, even though I am by far the most active user in this tag. [See top users here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-email/topusers).

With this in mind, there is always a bunch of mis-information being supplied by people who have much higher reps, but little knowledge on this specific niche. Quite often incorrect answers are flooding in from users following the `html` and `css` tags. Anyone who has worked with html email will know that modern web standards fail in most web clients.

I don't want to go all trigger happy on the downvotes, but it would be good if there was a way to distinguish who has what background, when answering the question at hand. Highlighting their particular expertise if you will.

In addition to the overall rep, I'd like to see one of the following added to the user info in the bottom right corner of each post:

1. Include user rep for the tags included in the question.
2. Display a small bronze/silver/gold badge with the applicable tag names. They would only display if the user has earned enough rep in one of the applicable tags.
3. Give users a ranking % or score based on each tag (this would keep scores relevant to the tag popularity)

Is this something that would be useful to the rest of the community?

Comment: That sounds interesting. Like "answered 5 minutes ago, Jon Skeet - 67 tag-expiriance, Infinity (rep) Infinity (gold) Infinity (silver) Infinity (bronze)"

Comment: Maybe it should be the number of standard deviations the user is from the median in the distribution of that tag. The reason for this is because some topics are low-traffic and may not have provided enough opportunity for users to develop multiple (if any) tags.

Comment: I'm with @dilbert; perhaps even something like `Top 2% in this tag` similar to what's found on the user profile screen.

Comment: @dilbert I agree. Currently I'm the only person to date [to get a bronze html-email badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3376/html-email?userid=1435513). It wouldn't really stand out against a bunch of silver and gold html and css badges.

Comment: I don't know that this feature would have any bearing whatsoever on your specific problem of people posting bad answers on `html-email`.  Nonetheless, it would be shiny and new, and I like shiny new features.

Comment: @dilbert I'd agree but I suppose that search will have a big impact (in terms of query time) on DB.

Comment: @Adriano, it's unlikely that such information (the number and types of tag badges a user has) changes frequently, and so the distributions and ratings don't need to be calculated frequently. Maybe once weekly, or something like that; definitely not per-page based.

Comment: I was just about to suggest this feature. It's really alarming how much of a halo effect high rep can have on the drive-by voter... allowing an inaccurate answer to earn undeserved upvotes. I certainly feel for you -particularly in the smaller tags where it's up to you to police that kind of thing.

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278430/how-to-view-total-reputation-generated-by-tag/320732#320732 for a current supported work around.