# How to view total reputation generated by tag?

Tags: support

Can I see the total amount of reputation, generated by tag? If you have three questions of tag `foo` and each is upvoted once, you would have a total reputation of `3 X 1 X 5 = 15` generated in relation to tag `foo`. If one of these questions is the single question of tag `bar`, then tag `bar` would have a total reputation of `1 x 1 x 5 = 5`. Also, if this question gets an answer, which is upvoted twice, than one must add to both `foo` and `bar` `1 x 2 x 10 = 20`. Can one generate such a report?

Comment: Can't you try your self on [sede](http://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/469150/how-to-view-total-reputation-generated-by-tag?UserId=1836143) calculates the amount of reputation, including bounties, per tag for a specific user:

```sql
-- userid: Your Userid

select t.tagname
     , sum(case 
       when posttypeid = 1 then  -- Q 
          case 
          when v.votetypeid = 2 then 5 -- upmod
          when v.votetypeid = 3 then -2 -- downmod
          else 0
          end
       when posttypeid = 2 then -- A
          case 
          when v.votetypeid = 1 then 15 -- accept
          when v.votetypeid = 2 then 10 -- upmod
          when v.votetypeid = 3 then -2 -- downmod
          when v.votetypeid = 9 then v.bountyamount
          else 0
          end
          end) as [Reputation]
       
from posts p 
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
left outer join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where p.owneruserid = ##userid:int?1836143## 
and p.posttypeid in (1,2)
and v.votetypeid in (1, 2, 3, 9)
group by t.tagname
```

You can find details of the [database schema on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede). Remember that SEDE updates only once a week, in the weekend.